# How to get entity class from table name in Doctrine?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working on a Symfony + Doctrine based project. Is it possible to query an entity class using a given table name?

I know that it is no problem to ask Doctrine which table name belongs to a given entity class but I need this the other way (table name -> entity class, NOT entity class -> table name).

Asking Doctrine for all table names of all configured entities does not work in my case, since I need this feature within a bundle which is used in different projects and thus does not know all the project entities...

Comment: `ClassMetadata::getAllMetadata()` should provide you with all the mappings (including `className => tableName`) known to the `EntityManager`. With the help of the `ManagerRegistry` you should be able to query all known orm managers. What's the problem with this approach? It shouldn't matter what project the bundle is installed on.

Comment: It appears that `ClassMetadata::getAllMetadata()` is not defined; I get: Error : Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata::getAllMetadata()